# Create a function for include template twig

Tags: php, templates, twig

I creat a function for include templates in my defualt page ...
this source for my function

```
{% macro partial(partialname) %}  
 {% include 'partials/_'~partialname ~'.twig' %} 
{% endmacro %}
```

when partialname included in defualt.twig and when extends defuat.twig in another template for sample login.twig  can't override block's partialname  in login.twig .... 
for sample I include

> 'partial/_main.twig'
>   in 
>   defualt.twig

and _main.twig has a block that name is 'main' now in file 'login.twig' i have this source:

```
{% extends 'defuatl.twig' %}
{% block main%}
@override
{% endblock %}
```

but any change in my result...

Comment: To override blocks in included templates you need to use `embed` rather than `include` not sure why you are trying to wrap that in a macro though

Comment: And check your spelling: `defuat` vs `default` vs `defualt`